# Setting up multi-file logging with inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am setting up my first multi-file project using modules (Python 3.6), and I am having some trouble setting up a coherent way to log. I want my whole project to have the same logging level across all modules, and know that child loggers inherit the properties of their parents. So when I have my 2 files set up like this:

main.py:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('a')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(ch)
import GUI

GUI.hello()
```

`GUI/__init__.py`:

```
import logging
module_logger = logging.getLogger('a.GUI')
module_logger.info(__name__ + ' imported')
def hello():
    module_logger.info('hello')
```

I get

```
GUI imported
hello
```

as expected. But when I substitute the logger names for `__name__`in both the root and module, (`logging.getLogger(__name__)`) in both cases, I get no output. I am trying to do it this way to avoid having to refactor etc in case something changes down the line. What am I missing? Or is there a better way to set up logging that may be more scalable etc.?

Thank you so much for your help!

EDIT: I've seen [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules), which works, but would like to have some more granularity if possible, like having custom names for the loggers etc. Though if not possible I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__name__` of the file executed is always `"__main__"`. Setting up a loggers by name will thus *not* have it be the root of the rest of your modules. In your case, you have the following loggers:

```
"__main__"  # from main.py
"GUI"       # from GUI/__init__.py
"GUI.bar"   # from GUI/bar.py (hypothetically)
```

Furthermore, you probably want to add more packages like `GUI` later on - these will form even more hierarchies!

So, how to solve this?

- Configure the root logger in `main`

  - Using the name `None` or `""` gives you the root logger for all others. Its settings are inherited by all others. While a library should not configure the root loggers, an application should.

    ```
    # main.py
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    ```

    This is preferable if your modules are actually a library, and your `main` is just one executable using it.
- Fixed name loggers

  - Same as you do now, explicitly setting logger names. This has the added benefit of decoupling your loggers from implementation details.

    ```
    # main.py
    logger = logging.getLogger('a')
    ```
- Package based loggers

  - If you reorganise all your modules into a single package, you can use the `__package__` name.

    ```
    # package/main.py
    logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)  # 'package'

    # package/GUI/__init__.py
    logger = logging.getLogger(__package__)  # 'package.GUI'
    ```

    Note that `main.py` should then be called as `python -m main`.
- Purpose based loggers

  - Use names appropriate to functionality, not position. Note that you can use the same name/logger multiple times!

    ```
    # GUI/__init__.py
    input_logger = logging.getLogger('a.input')
    output_logger = logging.getLogger('a.output')

    # GUI/buttons.py
    input_logger = logging.getLogger('a.input')
    ```

Note that using a hierarchy of loggers is *not* about scalability! The most performant approach is using the same logger everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If all your python module uses the exact same logger I highly recommend to use directly the 'logging.info('blabla')' instead of creating multiple loggers for each python files. That will suit your purpose best.
Florent